# Why does Ruby string formatting with hashes behave inconsistently across versions?

Tags: ruby

I wrote some code that used a "dynamic hash" to return values for keys, where the values were calculated.  I tested it under *irb* (RUBY_VERSION 2.3.3) and everything seemed good.  Below is a trivial example demonstrating the idea.

```
PROPS = Hash.new { |hash,key| key.to_s + "!" }
"Foo: %{foo} Bar: %{bar}" % PROPS  # => "Foo: foo! Bar: bar!"
PROPS[:xyzzy] # => "xyzzy!"
```

But then deploying my code into the environment where it used (a plugin for the modeling tool Sketchup) which apparently has Ruby 2.2.4 the string formatting example above yields a KeyError: key{foo} not found.

```
PROPS = Hash.new { |hash,key| key.to_s + "!" }
"Foo: %{foo} Bar: %{bar}" % PROPS  # KeyError: key{foo} not found
PROPS[:xyzzy] # => "xyzzy!"
```

But accessing the hash with any key works fine...  Reading at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf doesn't provided much in the way of specifying why hash defaults would not behave as expected.

Obviously I can do different things, like invent my own replacement functions and variable syntax.  As an aside, apparently the "hashes" passed to "%" or sprintf must actually BE Hash objects, violating Ruby's supposed duck-typing flexibility.

Comment: 'violating Ruby's supposed duck-typing flexibility.'
Well, that is why ruby implemented this feature from ruby 2.3 onwards. Upgrading to latest ruby will fix this issue

Comment: @Tachyons it does not fix _this issue_. Default in hash works in recent ruby, while using your own class implementing `def [](value); "#{value}!"; end` apparently _does not_. That still violates duck typing flexibility.

Comment: "As an aside, apparently the "hashes" passed to "%" or sprintf must actually BE Hash objects, violating Ruby's supposed duck-typing flexibility." – Does it really not call `to_hash`? That would be strange.

Comment: @Marvin Nice one. I can confirm that in ruby 2.1.5 the default proc for a hash will not be used in % interpolation. I am sure you can fake it though. If wanting to explore with pure ruby experiments with method_missing could help.

Comment: @Felix How would I "fake it"? Oops, never mind.

Comment: @Tachyons @mudasobwa My first try was what I thought was Ruby's strength, e.g, -  ` class SUBS; def [](k) "#{k}!!"; end; end; puts "%{foo}" % Foo.new` but that raises ArgumentError: one hash required (in 2.2. and 2.3.3)  I couldn't find any docs about what are the canonical methods that must be implemented for an object to be a "hash" (and Hash has 103 methods)  I tried adding has_key,key?,and fetch before I discovered how to create a hash with dynamic defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that it does not work in Ruby 2.1.5 .

I will give some hints on how you could find out which ruby code to define to get the stuff going without reading C or Ruby code from MRI.

I know, this is not a full answer, but the text is too long to give in a comment.

Following is an irb session

```
  >> detector = Object.new
  => #<Object:0x00000002257900>
  >> def detector.method_missing m
  >>   puts m.to_s
  >> end
  => :method_missing
  >> "Foo: %{fnoo} Bar: %{bar}" % detector
  to_ary
  to_hash
  ArgumentError: one hash required
      from (irb):37:in `%'
      from (irb):37
      from /home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

This tells us that during interpolation methods were called that are not implemented by our dummy "detector" Object (`to_hash` to be precisely; through other tests I know that to_ary is also called if given object is a Hash, so we can ignore that one).

It does however not tell us whether already something like `detector.class` or `detector is_a Hash?` etcpp. were called.

Now I await the downvotes ;)

Btw, if you want to dive in via C - and I came to believe that this is probably needed in this case - you can start digging here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6d728bdae9de565ad9d0b2fee2d4c2a33c6f4eac/sprintf.c#L579 (more or less "sprintf" on ruby 2.1).

Comment: It seems like the string formatting is using the underlying C implementation directly.  I made a class and implemented to_hash to return self. `class P; def to_hash() self; end; def has_key(k) true;  end; def [](k) "#{k}!!";  end; end; "%{foo}"% P.new`   It raised `TypeError: can't convert Q to Hash (Q#to_hash gives Q)`  So the underlying code precludes DuckTyping.  I also tried extending Hash and overriding methods, but after [], fetch, key? and has_key was insufficient gave up.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since it was useful to me, but really my question has no answer other than "it's a bug" or "that's just how it is"